# Does decreasing the length of the line between a harness and zip wire increase the velocity at which you travel?

Tags: gravity, velocity, popular-science

My friend is an instructor at an outdoor adventure centre which has lots of zip wires. The instructor's harness has a shorter line that attaches to the zip wire than the normal harness does and she claims that you go much faster with it. Is this true? I can't think of any reason as to why it would be MUCH faster but apparently their speed gun proved it.

**Edit:** Diagram for clarity

[image]

Comment: Did they prove it with different people in the same harness, or same person in different harnesses?  If so, I can think of 2 possibilities.  1)  long line could lead to a greater lag angle (how far behind the trolley the person is), which could cause binding of the trolley's pulleys.  2) the line itself has huge wind drag, which is unlikely to be a significant cause.

Comment: Could you add a diagram?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I thought the angle could be different and therefore make a difference but after thinking about it some more, I'm not actually sure there would be a difference in the angle.  Somebody should work out the math to see if there is any difference in the angle.

Comment: Added a diagram for clarity. I don't think anyone has been speed checked in both harnesses so technically no valid conclusions can be drawn. It's more of the average speed in the shorter harness is more than the average speed in the longer one and just the word of the instructors who have used both. The only thing I can think of as to why is could be quicker would be due to better/less worn pulleys in the instructor harness

Comment: Actually, it should be the other way around. You should be faster with the longer line because you are closer to the ground during the whole ride which means that you have less potential energy and more kinetic energy (=speed).

Comment: In my experience of these, there is more friction in the trolley than on the person, and there is some swinging backward and forward. A shorter line will make more rapid swinging, and *maybe* a quicker restoration of the sliding down conditions?

Comment: If I had to guess, the long harnesses for customers go with trolleys that have more resistance in the wheels.  It is not about the length of the line, but about making sure the customers don't arrive at the bottom with too much speed.  The instructors have training and gloves so they can slow down when needed.

Answer (score 1):

My first guess is that if *feels* faster since your eyes are closer to the line zipping by.  This the same effect that makes it look like you are going slower down the highway compared to distant buildings than to stuff at the edge of the road.

The shorter line would have slightly less wind resistance, but that should be a insignificant effect in the scheme of things.

Someone mentioned the angle of the dangle would be different between someone hanging from a long teather and a short teather, but there should be no difference for the same person as long as the weight of the teather is small compared to the weight of the body.

The weight of the person could matter though.  One clue is you said "she" for the instructor.  Women, especially physically fit women likely to be such instructors, will be lighter on average than the average customer.  She could indeed be zipping faster than most others, although this has nothing to do with teather length.  One flaw in your diagram is that you don't show the zip line sagging from the weight of the person.  The more the sag, the less of a downhill push the person gets.  Think of the limiting case where the line sags so much that you stop at a dead spot before the other end where you are lower than both ends.

Comment: You should maybe mention that the weight has nothing to do with how much she is accelerated by gravity. It matters for the roll in the zip line which will have a higher roll-resistance with a heavier person for mechanical reasons.

Comment: @Philipp: Right, accelleration due to gravity is the same regardless of weight.  If the friction is proportional to weight, then that cancels out too.  I don't know how significant friction of the pulley is.  They could be made with reasonably insignificant friction for this purpose, but maybe they aren't.  How much that varies due to weight is another question.

Comment: This sounds like something that should be tested. I wonder if it could be to do with the period of oscillations being shorter with a shorter line, though I don't really see how this would make much difference.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is years old, so the OP has probably moved on, but for the sake of those stumbling on this years later....

The quick answer is no, the length of the lanyard/tether, doesn't have any noticeable effect on the speed of the rider. What it may affect though, is rider positioning, which has a significant effect on wind drag and will change the speed.

For the last 15 years I have been a guide and then a designer/builder of such zip line tours. There are four primary variables that factor into the forces on a rider and their speed: rolling resistance (decelerating force), wind resistance (decelerating force), rider weight (accelerating force), and cable slope (accelerating force). Lanyard length technically would increase cross-sectional area which would increase wind resistance, but this would be negligible compared to other variables.

Rider weight and rolling resistance tend to be pretty static. Cable slope changes along the length of the cable, depending on installation pitch and tension (it's steeper at the beginning and flattens out towards the end), but also the amount a rider deflects the cable (a heavy person will deflect the cable more and therefore their RIDE PATH will be steeper at the beginning than a light persons ride path). Wind resistance is the hardest to account for because it depends on so many things like the direction and speed of the wind that day, the size of the rider, the clothes the rider is wearing, and most importantly, the rider positioning.

As a guide, we would always tell participants about "starfish" vs "canon ball" position. These drastically change the cross sectional area of the person, and therefore the amount of wind resistance. The very fastest ride position is "the pencil" which has the least wind resistance.

I experimented as a guide and could ride the same zip line on the same day with the same weather conditions, and the same hardware setup (same gear weight and rolling resistance), but ride one time in the starfish position and not even make it to the end, but the next time in the pencil position, and approach the braking zone at 40+ km/h.

So back to the question....

The lanyard length would have zero effect on rider weight, rolling resistance, or cable slope, but could effect the rider positioning which in turn would affect wind resistance.

The shorter guide lanyards are designed so guides can control their braking with a gloved leather hand on the cable. My theory is that the guide in question naturally leans back to avoid rubbing her helmet on the cable, which puts her in a more pencil-like form. The participants on the other hand, are having a grand old dangle on the longer lanyard and flapping in the breeze. So their wind resistances are very different.